# My Questions do not change when i click the NEXT button but the options change in my Tkinter Quiz App

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

[first question with its](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KYyO.png)

[The same question but with different options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHVMU.png)

```
 def display_options(self,qn):
    val = 0
    self.opt_selected.set(0)
    self.ques = questions[qn] #I think this is where the issue is
        
    

    for option in options[qn]:
        self.opts[val]['text'] = option
        val+=1
```

Comment: Please update the question to include a [mre]. At the moment, we have no idea if the problem lies in the `question` variable, or if there is something else that is affecting the updating of the question-text.

Comment: What is the error? Is that all the code?Refer to @HampusLarsson minimal reproducible example. Thanks